# Can a powerset be a member of the original set?

Tags: set-theory

Within ZFC set theory, is the following statement or its negative provable?

> There exists a set, $s$, whose powerset, $\mathcal{P}s$, is a member of $s$, i.e. $\mathcal{P}s \in s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: $s\in\wp(s)$, so if $\wp(s)\in s$, there would be an infinite descending $\in$-chain,

$$\ldots\in s\in\wp(s)\in s\in\wp(s)\in s\in\wp(s)\in s\,,$$

contradicting a [consequence of the axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists).